# Columnas desabilitadas hasta hacer click en un formulario

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario compuesto de tres columnas, lo que quiero es que a medida que se empieza a rellenar los datos desde la primera columna las otras no sean editables hasta que se le de el botón siguiente hasta el ultimo boton de enviar.
Mi código html es:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form id="form" data-parsley-validate novalidate>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <h5 class="card-header title-estado">Datos Específicos</h5>
            <div class="bd-example">
              <div id="name" class="form-group row">
                <label for="inputText0" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Nombre:</label>
                <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                  <input id="inputText0" type="text" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers">
                </div>
              </div> 
              <div id="gender" class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Género:</label>
                <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                  <div>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                      <input id="radio1" type="radio" required=""  name="button" class="custom-control-input">
                      <span class="custom-control-label">Femenino</span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                      <input id="radio2" type="radio" required=""  name="button" class="custom-control-input">
                      <span class="custom-control-label">Masculino</span>
                    </label>
                 </div>
                 <div class="card-body border-top">
                   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-style" type="submit">Siguiente</button>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
             <div class="card">
               <h5 class="card-header title-estado">Notas</h5>
               <div class="bd-example">
                 <div class="form-group row">
                   <label for="inputText1" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Matemática:</label>
                   <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                     <input id="inputText1" type="number" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" max="20">
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group row">
                   <label for="inputText2" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Geografía:</label>
                   <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                     <input id="inputText2" type="number" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" max="20">
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group row">
                   <label for="inputText3" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Historia:</label>
                   <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                     <input id="inputText3" type="number" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" max="20">
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="card-body border-top">
                   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-style" type="submit">Siguiente</button>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12">
             <div class="card">
               <h5 class="card-header title-estado">Otras Notas</h5>
               <div class="bd-example">
                 <div class="form-group row">
                   <label for="inputText4" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Economía:</label>
                   <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                     <input id="inputText4" type="number" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" max="20">
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group row">
                   <label for="inputText5" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Psicología:</label>
                   <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                     <input id="inputText5" type="number" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" max="20">
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group row">
                   <label for="inputText6" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Filosfía:</label>
                   <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                     <input id="inputText6" type="number" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" max="20">
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="card-body border-top">
                   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-style" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </form>
      </div>
```

Cuando se este llenando la primera columna del formulario los input de las otras dos columnas deben de estar en gris y no editables, para luego, una vez que se haga click en siguiente (de la primera columna) se habilite la siguiente columna para editarla, pero la tercera columna siga desabilitada, finalmente cuando se haya rellenado la segunda columna se haga click en siguiente se habilite la última y luego se envíe el formulario, no se si en javascript exista algo relacionado a desabilitar.
No tengo idea de que como hacer el código en javascript para esta función si alguien pudiera ayudarme.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Aqui coloco una validacion que te deshabilitara los campos de la seccion 2 y seccion 3, cuando completes los datos de la seccion 1 entonces se habilitara los campos de la seccion 2 y al completar la 2 se habilita la seccion 3, de esta forma no permitira ingresar datos hasta completar los campos de la seccion anterior.

Segundo: se modifico el codigo para las columnas de bootstrap porque no ajustaba el formulario en resoluciones de pantalla completa en desktop

Tercero: Se coloco value en los input radio para indicar asignar contenido una vez seleccionado.

Aqui esta el codigo con su validacion de los formularios en JQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form id="form" data-parsley-validate novalidate>
          <div class="row">
            <!-- col 1 -->
            <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
              <div class="card">
                <h5 class="card-header title-estado">Datos Específicos</h5>
                  <div class="bd-example">
                    <div id="name" class="form-group row">
                      <label for="inputText0" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Nombre:</label>
                      <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                        <input id="inputText0" type="text" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers">
                      </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div id="gender" class="form-group row">
                      <label class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Género:</label>
                      <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                        <div>
                          <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input id="radio1" type="radio" required=""  name="button" 
                            class="custom-control-input" value="Femenino">
                            <span class="custom-control-label">Femenino</span>
                          </label>
                          <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input id="radio2" type="radio" required=""  name="button" 
                            class="custom-control-input" value="Masculino">
                            <span class="custom-control-label">Masculino</span>
                          </label>
                       </div>
                       <div class="card-body border-top">
                         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-style" type="submit">Siguiente</button>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <!-- col 2-->
                 <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12"></div>
                   <div class="card">
                     <h5 class="card-header title-estado">Notas</h5>
                     <div class="bd-example">
                       <div class="form-group row">
                         <label for="inputText1" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Matemática:</label>
                         <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                           <input id="inputText1" type="number" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" max="20">
                         </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group row">
                         <label for="inputText2" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Geografía:</label>
                         <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                           <input id="inputText2" type="number" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" max="20">
                         </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group row">
                         <label for="inputText3" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Historia:</label>
                         <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                           <input id="inputText3" type="number" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" max="20">
                         </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="card-body border-top">
                         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-style" type="submit">Siguiente</button>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                   <!-- col 3-->
                   <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12"></div>
                   <div class="card">
                     <h5 class="card-header title-estado">Otras Notas</h5>
                     <div class="bd-example">
                       <div class="form-group row">
                         <label for="inputText4" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Economía:</label>
                         <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                           <input id="inputText4" type="number" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" max="20">
                         </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group row">
                         <label for="inputText5" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Psicología:</label>
                         <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                           <input id="inputText5" type="number" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" max="20">
                         </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group row">
                         <label for="inputText6" class="col-5 col-lg-5 col-form-label text-left label-style">Filosfía:</label>
                         <div class="col-7 col-lg-7">
                           <input id="inputText6" type="number" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Numbers" min="0" max="20">
                         </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="card-body border-top">
                         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-style" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </form>
            </div>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <script>
    // validacion 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      
       // deshabilitar lista de input  para sec 2 y sec 3
       $( "input[type=number]" ).each(function( index ) {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        });


       // habilitar campos para seccion 2
       $("input[type=radio], input[type=text]").change(function(){
          // campo radio y text 
          var nombre = $("input[type=text]").val();
          var genero = $('input:radio[name=button]:checked').val();

              // detectar campo indefinido para radio
              if(!(typeof(genero)  === "undefined")) {
                  // si hay datos en sec 1 habilita sec 2, en caso contrario lo deshabilita
                if (genero.length>0 && nombre.length>0) {
                    $("input[type=number]").eq(0).prop('disabled', false);
                    $("input[type=number]").eq(1).prop('disabled', false);
                    $("input[type=number]").eq(2).prop('disabled', false);
                } else {
                    $("input[type=number]").eq(0).prop('disabled', true);
                    $("input[type=number]").eq(1).prop('disabled', true);
                    $("input[type=number]").eq(2).prop('disabled', true);
                }
              }

          });
         

        // habilitar campos para seccion 3
        $("input[type=number]").slice(0,3).change(function() {
            // tomar longitud de campos nota sec 2
            var mat = $("input[type=number]").eq(0).val().length;
            var geo = $("input[type=number]").eq(1).val().length;
            var his = $("input[type=number]").eq(2).val().length;
            // si hay datos en sec 2 muestra sec 3
            if (mat>0 && geo>0 && his>0) {
                    $("input[type=number]").eq(3).prop('disabled', false);
                    $("input[type=number]").eq(4).prop('disabled', false);
                    $("input[type=number]").eq(5).prop('disabled', false);
                } else {
                    $("input[type=number]").eq(3).prop('disabled', true);
                    $("input[type=number]").eq(4).prop('disabled', true);
                    $("input[type=number]").eq(5).prop('disabled', true);
                }
           
        }); //  fin if 
 
     });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```